# How to set children view draw out side of it's parent view

Tags: android

I have a children view in a layout, and this layout in other layout that is difference file. Children view is cliped by it parent, i already set `clipChildren="false"` to all parent view. My min sdk is 21.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_app_start"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context="com.jxs.agmusic.home.AppStart">

<com.jxs.agmusic.home.tabbar.TabBar
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

tab_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:background="@color/MainBackground">

<View
    android:id="@+id/mini_player"
    android:background="@color/Info"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I try to put `tab_bar.xml` content to `activity_main.xml` and work well, but i still want to split two file.

Comment: what about negative margin? Did you try this??

Comment: you can use layout placeholder `<include layout="@layout/tab_bar.xml"/>` in your activity_main.xml in case you want separate files

Comment: @MohammadZarei I have set `android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"` to children view.

Comment: @AbhinavPuri Yes, this is a solution if it can't work with a custom view.